# Web game architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture

I am working on a web based game in JS (typescript), with a node.js server and AJAX. I know very little of game based architecture, and as the game grows, it becomes more and more complicated which made me think of rebuilding it with a proper architecture. What tuts/books should I read about architecture, knowing that a web-based game with strong logic on both client and server side requires a somewhat specific knoweldge ? Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe this is better suited for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Sirko is right, this has very little to do with `node.js` and sounds like you need to learn about game loops, bitmapped graphics & sprites, maybe WebGL, some networking, etc.